# LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file cannot read 0x458

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty new to qt and i'm trying to create a widget that showing my webcam using qt and opencv. As the title has stated that i'm stuck at the LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file cannot read 0x458.  After having done some research, i discovered that this issues have been addressed in multiple topic, but not with 0x458 in particular

Any aid would be greatly appriciated, from the bottom of my heart

here's my code:
.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-08-10T12:27:53
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TutorialOpenCV
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
        myvideocapture.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
        myvideocapture.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/ -lopencv_world451
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/ -lopencv_world451d
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/ -lopencv_world451

INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15
LIBS += C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_world451.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib\opencv_world451d.lib


INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../opencv/build/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../opencv/build/include


INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\release\install\include


LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_core451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_highgui451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_imgproc451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_features2d451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_calib3d451.dll

INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\release\install\include\opencv2
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\release\install\include\opencv
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\release\include
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\install\x64\mingw\bin\libopencv_core451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\install\x64\mingw\bin\libopencv_highgui451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\install\x64\mingw\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\install\x64\mingw\bin\libopencv_imgproc451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\install\x64\mingw\bin\libopencv_features2d451.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\install\x64\mingw\bin\libopencv_calib3d451.dll
```

myvideocapture.cpp:

```
#include "myvideocapture.h"
#include <QDebug>

MyVideoCapture::MyVideoCapture(QObject *parent)
    : QThread { parent }
    , mVideoCap { ID_CAMERA }
{
}
void MyVideoCapture::run()
{
    if (mVideoCap.isOpened())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            mVideoCap >> mFrame;
            if (!mFrame.empty())
            {
                cv::rectangle(mFrame, cv::Point(10, 10), cv::Point(401, 401), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);

                mPixmap = cvMatToQPixmap(mFrame);
                emit newPixmapCaptured();
            }
        }
    }
}

QImage MyVideoCapture::cvMatToQImage(const cv::Mat &inMat)
{
    switch (inMat.type())
    {
        // 8-bit, 4 channel
        case CV_8UC4:
        {
            QImage image(inMat.data, inMat.cols, inMat.rows, static_cast<int>(inMat.step), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
            return image;
        }
        // 8-bit, 3 channel
        case CV_8UC3:
        {
            QImage image(inMat.data, inMat.cols, inMat.rows, static_cast<int>(inMat.step), QImage::Format_RGB888);
            return image.rgbSwapped();
        }
        // 8-bit, 1 channel
        case CV_8UC1:
        {
    #if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 5, 0)
            QImage image(inMat.data, inMat.cols, inMat.rows, static_cast<int>(inMat.step), QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
    #else
            static QVector<QRgb>  sColorTable;

            // only create our color table the first time
            if (sColorTable.isEmpty())
            {
                sColorTable.resize(256 );

                for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
                {
                    sColorTable[i] = qRgb(i, i, i );
                }
            }

            QImage image(inMat.data,
                         inMat.cols, inMat.rows,
                         static_cast<int>(inMat.step),
                         QImage::Format_Indexed8 );

            image.setColorTable(sColorTable );
    #endif
            return image;
        }
        default:
        {
            qWarning()<< "ASM::cvMatToQImage()- cv::Mat image type not handled in switch:" << inMat.type();
            break;
        }
    }
    return QImage();
}

QPixmap MyVideoCapture::cvMatToQPixmap(const cv::Mat &inMat)
{
    return QPixmap::fromImage(cvMatToQImage(inMat));
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "myvideocapture.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mOpenCV_videoCapture = new MyVideoCapture(this);

    connect(mOpenCV_videoCapture, &MyVideoCapture::newPixmapCaptured, this, [&]()
    {
        ui->opencvFrame->setPixmap(mOpenCV_videoCapture->pixmap().scaled(500, 500));
    });
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    mOpenCV_videoCapture->terminate();
}

void MainWindow::on_iniciarOpenCV_button_clicked()
{
    mOpenCV_videoCapture->start(QThread::HighestPriority);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyle("fusion");
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: If msvc is the compiler you can't link with dlls in native c++. You need to link with the import libraries `.lib` that go with the dll. And these must have been compiled with Visual Studio 2015 to 2019 and must match the architecture 32 or 64 bit of your application.

Comment: In my previous comment I assume your msvc compiler is the one shipped with VS2015 to 2019. These are binary compatible with each other but not compatible with previous versions of VS or mingw: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160)

Comment: I'm not quite get it, could you explain it a bit clearer?

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio 2015 to 2019 as your compiler, none of the `LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_core451.dll` are correct. These are only correct for mingw. Instead for msvc (microsoft compiler that comes with Visual Studio) it should be `LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_core451.lib` provided this .lib file was compiled with one of VS2015 to 2019.

Comment: Your error is the same as this 2014 question: [https://forum.qt.io/topic/49464/lnk1107-invalid-or-corrupt-file-cannot-read-at-error](https://forum.qt.io/topic/49464/lnk1107-invalid-or-corrupt-file-cannot-read-at-error)

Comment: but my compiler is mingw 64 bit, i even try to compile with mscv 64 bit, same result, not working

Comment: ***i'm stuck at the LNK1107*** is a msvc error code. mingw will not have that error code.